# Unable to see the battery health management in MacBook pro mid-2015

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I just got the motherboard of my macbook changed because there was issue with the charge flow.
After installing new one, I saw a new option of battery health management which was telling me the health of my battery. But now I am not able to see that option.
Nothing substantial has changed in my computer, I don't remember updating anything.
My MacBook pro is mid-2015 15 inch and OS is mojave.
According to [this answer](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252301623)
, my MacBook is too old to have that option. But I saw that option after the motherboard change but it is now gone. What kind of non-deterministic behaviour is this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that feature should not be available on your model of MacBook Pro.

As to why you saw it initially, then I can only guess that it was a bug. It's possible that the change in logic board was a factor in confusing the OS.

But ultimately, you should not expect or rely on enabling this feature.

There are third-party battery management utilities, like [Coconut Battery](https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/), which provide more in-depth data. But you can't alter the way it charges. Your Mac just doesn't have the right hardware.